# jquery datatable bootstrap not working properly when published

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, datatables, webforms

I found out what was causing my jquery datatable pagination to not work. Seems like the problem is when i use this on references

```
dataTables.bootstrap4.css/js
```

here are my bundles

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/jquery").Include(
           "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/angularjs").Include(
           "~/Scripts/angular.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/adminlte").Include(
            "~/AdminLTE/dist/js/adminlte.js",
            "~/AdminLTE/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js",
            "~/AdminLTE/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js",  
            "~/AdminLTE/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.js",         
            "~/AdminLTE/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
            "~/AdminlTE/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/jqueryui").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));            

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/js").Include(
        "~/Scripts/MasterPage/menu-selection.js",
        "~/Scripts/MasterPage/notification.js",
        "~/Scripts/Pages/main.js",
        "~/Scripts/Pages/DataTable.js",
        "~/Scripts/Pages/Validation.js",
        "~/Scripts/Pages/Datepicker.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/fontawesome").Include(
            "~/Scripts/fontawesome/all.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/iziToast").Include(
            "~/Scripts/iziToast/iziToast*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/modernizr").Include(
           "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/login-form").Include(
            "~/Content/Login/login-formas.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/fontawesome").Include(
            "~/Content/fontawesome-all*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/iziToast").Include(
            "~/Content/iziToast*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/adminlte").Include(
            "~/AdminLTE/dist/css/adminlte*",
            "~/AdminLTE/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.css",
            "~/AdminLTE/plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css",
            "~/AdminLTE/plugins/iCheck/all.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
           "~/Content/MasterPages/layout.css",
           "~/Content/MasterPages/fieldset.css"));
    }
```

and on master page

```
 <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">



    <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/adminlte") %>
    <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/fontawesome") %>
    <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/iziToast") %>
    <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/css") %>

    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/jquery") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/angularjs") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/adminlte") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/jqueryval") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/fontawesome") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/iziToast") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/js") %>

</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

on localhost it works fine, but when i publish it to a folder in IIS ONLY the pagination does not work...

Is there anyway i can keep using this style on host?

Comment: check your browser console error if any initialization error occurs or not.Also check if two or more javascript files conflict or not.

Comment: There are no errors, none detected in chrome or firefox on console

Comment: you are using three different js for datatables itself                                                1)/Scripts/Pages/DataTable.js, 2)/AdminLTE/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js,                                              3) /AdminLTE/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.js, which might be conflicting with each other try to remove unnecessary script file and try again

Comment: I'll check back at the office but i doubt it's due to this 'cause this is being used on the AdminLTE page. the 1st js script is just initializing the plugin for multiple tables